# How to install multiple ipython 3.0 kernels (python 2.7, python 3.4, etc...) with anaconda under linux?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

Ipython 3.0 (Jupyter) allows to choose which kernel (python 2.7, python 3.4, etc...) to use when creating a new ipython notebook. How can I install multiple ipython notebook kernels under Continuum Anaconda?

Comment: What's wrong with asking here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to make separate conda environments for Python 2 and 3 (see info elsewhere on how to do this), with IPython installed in both of them. Then, in each environment, run:

```
ipython kernelspec install-self
```

This registers that kernel so IPython can see it from outside the environment.

If you want more kernelspecs for different environments, look at the files in `~/.ipython/kernels` to see how to describe them.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly! for anyone interested [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/development/kernels.html) you can find how to write a kernel spec file.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648412/anaconda-python-3-and-2-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook) and it's answer provide step by step instructions for making the environments and setting up jupyter in anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

install-self is being deprecated:  https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/23

```
install-self
    [DEPRECATED] Install the IPython kernel spec directory for this Python.
```

Try

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --display-name "Python (current_env)"
source activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

instead.

Reference: http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html